# Why are my builds failing with "Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 100"

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build one of our older projects that uses Gradle 4.9.  I'm getting build failures with the message `Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 100`, but I can't find any information on what that code actually *means*.  Is there a reference somewhere with these error codes?  I've been unable to find one, but maybe I'm just not looking in the right place.

Comment: try adding `--debug` to your gradle command and try to find the cause.

Comment: @michalk I've used the various debug switches, but no actual cause is ever shown. I just want to know what that `100` actually freaking _means_.

Comment: Are you on linux?

Comment: This has happened on mac and in Linux docker containers both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that exit code 100 refers to a missing file.  After rebuilding the project in three or four different ways, I discovered that a step was errantly deleting a required certificate file, and the Spark service initialization function was bombing (without any kind of error message, which is *awesome*).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if a test or any code that is executed by a test is using `System.exit`. This shuts down the test worker and Gradle assumes it shutdown properly. See this [open issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11195).

Comment: I suppose it's possible that Spark is hard exiting under the hood.  We're not doing it in our code.